# Chilitags Microsoft Visual Studio Windows 64 Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2012, computer-vision

thank you in advance!

I am currently trying just to run the sample code for Chilitags a C++ library for the detection and identification of 2D fiducial markers. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 x64 on Windows, I have tried to run this code and I have gotten these errors:

```
Error #1:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl chilitags::Chilitags::setFilter(int,float)" (?setFilter@Chilitags@chilitags@@QEAAXHM@Z) referenced in function main

Error #2:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl chilitags::Chilitags::Chilitags(void)" (??0Chilitags@chilitags@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main

Error #3:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::map<int,class cv::Matx<float,4,2>,struct std::less<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,class cv::Matx<float,4,2> > > > __cdecl chilitags::Chilitags::find(class cv::Mat const &,enum chilitags::Chilitags::DetectionTrigger)" (?find@Chilitags@chilitags@@QEAA?AV?$map@HV?$Matx@M$03$01@cv@@U?$less@H@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBHV?$Matx@M$03$01@cv@@@std@@@4@@std@@AEBVMat@cv@@W4DetectionTrigger@12@@Z) referenced in function main

Error #4:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl chilitags::Chilitags::~Chilitags(void)" (??1Chilitags@chilitags@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
```

Code (detect-live.cpp)
https://github.com/chili-epfl/chilitags/tree/master/samples/detection

Let me know if you need any other information to help!

Comment: You need to include the Chilitags library in your VS project.  You can do that using the properties for the linker.

Comment: Do you have it working on Win32? IOW, is " 64 bits" relevant?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I actually have the Chilitags library included in the project. When I enter -  #include <chilitags.hpp> I do not get any sort of error.

Comment: @MSalters I have only tried on Win64, it may not be relevant but I put it there anyway. I am able to get other code to work so I don't think it has to do with my configuration of VS.

Comment: @MatthewPurri: `#include` means the compiler can find the library _headers_. Can the linker find the library itself?

Comment: @MSalters Do you know how I would check for that?

Comment: @MatthewPurri: Is there any Chilitags symbol from the library which _is_ resolved? If not, then the library isn't found. Dependency Walker (aka Depends.EXE) can check this.